# Trying to understand why the constant of integration was ignored on this RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, equation

I am watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yikT4KayA70&index=26&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXXnp1Q4us-Vi7HqHE33AtzA) where the guy deducts the voltage across the capacitor during the transient phase.

[image]

There is an integral, in the middle of the equations. The guy integrates that and there is no constant of integration after that.

This is not just this guy, I am not aware of any of the capacitor/inductor formulas where the tutor considers them.

Why is that? Why can you simply ignore the constant of integration for all these equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the constant of integration is taken care of here: -

[image]

\$V_0\$ is the initial condition of the capacitor: -

[image]

And, when the left-hand integral is resolved \$V_0\$ is properly handled. For the right-hand integral having "0" as a limit means there won't be a "k" factor.

Comment: are you telling me that if the integral has a range, like \$ \int_0^t \$ or \$ \int_{Q_0}^Q \$ is it ok to ignore the constant of integration?

Comment: When the integral gets resolved and the limits applied you get an (U+K)-(L+K) situation where U is the upper limit and L is the lower limit. K (the constant) cancels but it was a long time ago that I learned this LOL.

Comment: brilliant, thanks. What you said gave me a lead to research the topic and you are right. When the integral is defined the constant of integration is cancelled and the limit situations are handled. THANKS, I LOVE YOU!

Comment: Easy now chap LOL

Comment: haha !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

At t=0 the switch is open and thus current flowing is zero.

The usual assumption in such example cases is that circuit is in steady state when t<0 which means the voltage across the capacitor is also zero.

As a result the constant on integration, the initial conditions, are zero.

I agree it is a bit sloppy as it isn't always the case and sometimes the dynamics of the circuit and the bias point does result in the constant of integration being non-zero

Comment: Yes I agree. It appears that the solution is doing a log of assumptions. The problem is that this solution is the most complete I have found. If you know some document online, book or something where all these conditions are considered, for RL, RC and RLC, please let me know. Thanks.